# Newcomers Treating Site Like A Forum

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

ever since following this site on Facebook, I've started to see some very low quality questions.

edit: not just "Newcomers Treating Site Like A Forum" but a few related issues too.

Did the influx of low quality questions start recently, or did I just start to see them thanks to Facebook?

Comment: It might be more constructive to ask about what to say to (i.e. how to welcome) newcomers.

Comment: Which questions, for example?

Comment: for example, http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/what-are-the-differences-between-hinduism-and-buddhism the answer by Oswulf is very subjective. Should we give constructive feedback or just close the question, since it's a duplicate?

Comment: I'm not sure what we can do about unsourced answers like that... I guess downvote or comment on them. The problem begins when opinion-based answers start getting upvoted and we never get at the "right" answer. I think constructively critical comments help prevent that.

Comment: could we perhaps attract religious scholars? some very impressive stuff is on Wikipedia, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Vedic_religion but I don't think I could do the material justice.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but I don't think FB is related.

People are asking broad, open ended questions, often with 6 or 7 broad open ended questions.  And then long back and forth discussions get going in the comments.

Another sign of problems is the question never really has one answer that is accepted and the top voted answer doesn't seem to be a "clincher" like I see in the programming sites.

If we had more questions, we could raise the quality by killing off the worst questions, but with only a handuful of questions a-day, we are killing of only the worst of the worst questions and making do with what we have left.

If we get more volume, the built in systems in SE will kick in and the front page will start to show the high quality questions and the low quality ones will sink out of sight.